# Kubernetes - Kubectl - What format is client data in?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, minikube

I currently have a kubernetes cluster I've set up - I want to build some monitoring infrastructure. I've built a simple library in ruby that can communicate with a kube cluster. For minikube this is fine as I can put the client key and the client cert in. For my kops AWS instance however I have two values:

- client-certificate-data
- client-key-data

I have no idea what format these are in - how do i convert them into pem encoded certificates so i can use them with my library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the kubernetes source code this is simply the base64 encoded data. Running a ruby base64 decode gives me the certificates I need.